# Is using System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng to sign and verify data thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net-core, thread-safety, x509certificate

I have an instance of `X509Certificate2` that holds an instance of `System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng`imported from `.pfx` file.

I don't want to read the file from disk every time I need to use it.

Is it safe to just have one global instance that is used by multiple threads?

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 on Linux and Windows.

Comment: You don't need to go to the file system each time; cache the `pfx` file

Comment: Yes, I know, but I still have to create these X509Certificate2 objects over and over, and I'm pretty sure that it's going to create a bunch of big allocations anyways. For now I'm going to be looking for some polling solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `RSACng` class is not thread-safe.

Also, be aware that this class is not available on Linux or Mac. It is Windows-only implementation. So keed abstract `RSA` class reference everywhere in the application instead of this particular implementation.